# passing variable from jQuery ajax to nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

i am trying to pass a variable from jQuery to nodejs, but i am not getting the right results, nodejs returns [object Object]. how can it return a string variable on nodejs side.

```
  $('.test').click(function(){
      var tsId = "Hello World";
      alert(tsId);
      console.log(tsId);
      $.ajax({
        'type': 'post',
        'data':tsId,
        'url': '/test/testing',
        'success': function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
      })
    });


 router.post('/testing', function(req, res) {

   var tsID = req.body;
   console.log("stsID "+tsID );\\ outputs [object Object]

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this way:

You should pass an object in ajax `data`, which contains your `Hello World` string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data:{str:tsId},
    url: '/test/testing',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
 });
```

In node.js file use this:

```
 router.post('/testing', function(req, res) {
    var tsID = req.body;
    console.log("stsID "+tsID.str );
 });
```

Comment: outputs: {"Hello World":""} its key value

Comment: What do you receive in console when you try `console.log("stsID "+tsID );` ?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: @KarishKarish, I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Do you need express server to be running? @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut

Answer (score 0):

Try  console logging tsID.data or tsID.tsId.  What do you get?  What do you get if you throw a debugger before your console log and write "tsID"  in the console?