# Passing data from AJAX to route in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ajax, routes

I don't know what went wrong, But here is my code:

AJAX file:

```
$(function(){
    $('.markreviewed').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var reviewid = $('.reviewid').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/a/'+reviewid,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                vid: reviewid
            },
            success: function(res){
                console.log('done');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Route file:

```
rtr.put('/a/:vid', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
  })
```

Console Output:

```
`done`
```

Terminal Output:

```
{}
```

Even after using body-parser middleware to parse JSON data.

No help in question: [passing variable from jQuery ajax to nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665948/passing-variable-from-jquery-ajax-to-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting down the Internet, I finally encountered the problem in the code. Posting the solution of above problem:

```
$(function(){
    $('.markreviewed').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var reviewid = $('.reviewid').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/a/'+reviewid,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',  // to parse data in json format
            data: JSON.stringify({vid: reviewid}), // it is important to stringify the data 
            success: function(res){
                console.log('done');
            }
        })
    })
})
```